# AWK Not repeating identical fields on records

Tags: awk

I'd like to present some kind of data :

```
A;01;data_1;CP
A;01;data_15;aP
A;01;data_23;Com
A;01;data_106;id
```

this way

```
A;01;data_1;CP
;;data_15;aP
;;data_23;Com
;;data_106;id
```

Is there a simple way to do this with awk ?

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: You should try adding more information about the question. eg. How is the output obtained from input. etc

Comment: Also it is expected on columns 1,2 only or could be anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, don't know if this is that simple...

```
awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i==a[i]) $i="";else a[i]=$i }1' file
```

The script set the input and output delimiter to `;`

Loop through all parameters of each line and empty the parameter content if this one was the same as the last line.

Comment: This is actually the *same* logic as my answer but posted seconds before me. Looks like we had the exact same idea. :)

Comment: @hek2mgl Indeed same idea at the same time :-) The only minor difference is the `printt` statement is replaced here by `1` which will trigger the default action in `awk` aka printing the whole line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `awk` script:

```
# dedup.awk

BEGIN {
    # Setting input and output delimiter to ';'
    FS=OFS=";"
}

{
    # Iterate trough all fields
    for(i=1;i<NF+1;i++) {
        # If the previous record's field at this index has
        # the same value as this field then set this field
        # to an empty string
        if(p[i]==$i) {
            $i=""
        } else {
           # Otherwise update the array that keeps
           # information about the previous record(s)
           p[i] = $i
        }
    }
    # Print the record
    print
}
```

You execute it like this:

```
awk -f dedup.awk input.file
```